# Perl: inc::Module::Install in Makefile.PL and installing executable

Tags: perl, executable

I'm writing a CPAN module and using inc::Module::Install 1.00 in Makefile.PL. The project has an executable perl script that needs to be installed into the defined location for runnable scripts. Given the script is

bin/foo

What is the correct parameters to pass?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`install_script`](http://p3rl.org/Module%3a%3aInstall#install_script). In your `Makefile.PL` add:

```
install_script 'bin/foo';
```